# How do I display coordinates of each polygon corner in the attributes table

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates

Is there a way to display coordinates of each corner of a polygon in the attributes table?

My end goal is to create a map that shows point numbers and coordinates for each corner of a polygon.

Comment: Easiest way should be using `geom_to_wkt()`.

Comment: How many corner have your polygon ? If they are complex using some bounding box corner may be wise. That beeing said have a look at these style : https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/141/ , you could probably modify the polygonZ one to display xy value...